# Flash editor changes font style when I'm done editing text. Suggestions?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, flash-cs5, flash-cs5.5

I'm using a custom font called "Quint" in a flash file. I have two styles for it installed on my machine, Medium and Italic. I want to use the Medium font. After I type in the text and take the focus away from the text field in the editor, it appears to have gone italic. Why does this happen? It is just classic, static text!

Video of my problem: http://screencast.com/t/fOoF4qu9

I'm using Adobe CS5.5.

Comment: I fixed my issue by uninstalling the font, and then only installing the medium style. Not sure why I can't have both on my machine, but whatever...

Comment: The problem could be with the font itself.You will also want to embed your font into the swf.

Comment: Normally I would embed the font, but I don't anticipate it being dynamic and I have to keep the final SWF's file size below 40k.

The problem could lie with the font, as I had gotten it from my employer's digital library. So I don't know where it had originally came from.

Comment: Fonts should always be suspect because they can be of varying quality. They might display to the screen ok, but sometimes other data for the font is missing that is required by Flash. Or I had a font from 1992 that a client gave me that wasn't working. Go figure.